# Getting undefined variable in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

In the `ngOnInit()` function I receive data from a service for use throughout the rest of my component. My issue is that after i save this data in a variable, it is undefined anywhere outside of the subscribe. I'm not sure why.

Code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  imagesPerRow: number;

  constructor(private backend : HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.backend.getGrid().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log("1: " + data);
      this.imagesPerRow = parseInt(data);
      console.log("2: " + this.imagesPerRow);
    });

    console.log("3: " + this.imagesPerRow);
  }
}
```

My console in chrome outputs:

```
3: undefined
1: 2
2: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.backend.getGrid()` is of type observable so it is called asynchronously. `console.log("3: " + this.imagesPerRow);` is outside of it, so this line gets executed first. Therefore you are getting `undefined`. It is declared within the observable function

Comment: You answered this already yourself when you just check the log output:

Log "3" is printed first, BEFORE the data is received or set ("1", "2"). The reson for this is simple: the code in the subscrible block is triggered when data is ready, while the log-output for "3" is executed immediately after subscribing.

Comment: Once the subscribe block is executed, `imagesPerRow` will be automatically updated in HTML. As you can see in your console.log. in the second line the variable is no more undefined